# How to edit column names in datatable function when running R shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I'm using datatable function from DT package in R Shiny and I want that the user of my app can edit the column names (the variable names). Is there any option to do that?

For now I'm using a text input "old_var_name", a text input "new_var_name" and an actionbutton "update_variable_name". But at this point, I'm only able to change on variable name at the time. I want the user to be able to change as much as variable names he wants.

Server:

```
tab <- eventReactive(input$import,{
inFile <- input$file1
if (is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)

tabledata <- read.xlsx(inFile$datapath,startRow=1,sheet = 1)
})

name_temp <- eventReactive(input$var_name,{
if (input$old_name == ""){
  colnames(tab())
} else {
    c(colnames(tab())[1:(which(colnames(tab()) == input$old_name)-1)],input$new_name,
    colnames(tab())[(which(colnames(tab()) == input$old_name)+1):length(colnames(tab()))])
}
})

final_rename <- reactive({
d <- tab()
colnames(d) <- name_temp()
d
})

output$tabledata <- DT::renderDataTable({
if (input$var_name == 0) {
  DT::datatable(tab(),editable = T)
} else {
  DT::datatable(final_rename(),editable = T)
}
})
```

UI:

```
tabPanel("Table",h1("Table",align="center") ,
actionButton(inputId = "import", label = "Import data"),br(),br(),                           
splitLayout(textInput(inputId = "old_name", label = "Old variable name"),                           
textInput(inputId = "new_name", label = "New variable Name")),
actionButton(inputId = "var_name", label = "Update Variable name"),br(),br(),
DT::dataTableOutput("tabledata"))
```

Is there any suggestion to achieve that or any option with datatable that I can use and then the user will be able to change all variable names he wants?

Comment: look up data.table::setnames(), it will work better for this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with a context menu. Right-click on a column header to edit it. Press 'Escape' when done, or simply move the mouse outside the text input box. This solution does not interfere with the sorting.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- c(
  "$.contextMenu({",
  "  selector: '#table th',", 
  "  trigger: 'right',",
  "  autoHide: true,",
  "  items: {",
  "    text: {",
  "      name: 'Enter column header:',", 
  "      type: 'text',", 
  "      value: ''", 
  "    }",
  "  },",
  "  events: {",
  "    show: function(opt){",
  "      $.contextMenu.setInputValues(opt, {text: opt.$trigger.text()});",
  "    },",
  "    hide: function(opt){",
  "      var $this = this;",
  "      var text = $.contextMenu.getInputValues(opt, $this.data()).text;",
  "      var $th = opt.$trigger;",
  "      $th.text(text);",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});" 
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.8.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.css"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.8.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.js")
  ),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris[1:3,], callback = JS(callback))
  }, server = FALSE)  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to retrieve the new column values so they are updated in the dataset being shown? I've tried to do it, but since I am not very familiar with JS, I failed.
Thank you!

Comment: I've modified the function executed when hiding, it is:
`hide: function(opt) {
     Shiny.onInputChange('oldColumnValue', opt.$trigger.text())
     var $this = this;
     var text = $.contextMenu.getInputValues(opt, $this.data()).text;
     var $th = opt.$trigger;
     $th.text(text);
     Shiny.onInputChange('newColumnValue', text)`

Comment: Hi Stéphane - Do you think there might've been changes with this javascript code matching R 4.0 today?

Comment: This solution is not any longer working (at least under R 4.1.0).

Comment: @micsky I've just tried with R 4.1.0 and it works fine.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent That's right, my apologies. You're example works well. I am working with modules, so I tried modularizing your code snippetand that's why it didn't work for me. There must be something in the JS, because the example below works well with modularized code. Do you maybe have a clue why this is happening?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Just to let you know:  I now recognized it's not the JS code itself but the head tags which I obviously didn't place correct. Still don't know what's the problem here but I found another solution anyway.

Comment: @micsky Glad to hear that. You can post your solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a friendly way except that it interferes with the sorting. So it is nice only if the sorting is disabled. Double-click on a column header to edit it, and press Tab to escape.

```
library(DT)

callback <- c(
  "table.on('dblclick.dt', 'thead th', function(e) {",
  "  var $th = $(this);",
  "  var index = $th.index();",
  "  var colname = $th.text(), newcolname = colname;",
  "  var $input = $('<input type=\"text\">')",
  "  $input.val(colname);",
  "  $th.empty().append($input);",
  "  $input.on('change', function(){",
  "    newcolname = $input.val();",
  "    if(newcolname != colname){",
  "      $(table.column(index).header()).text(newcolname);",
  "    }",
  "    $input.remove();",
  "  }).on('blur', function(){",
  "    $(table.column(index).header()).text(newcolname);",
  "    $input.remove();",
  "  });",
  "});"
)

datatable(iris[1:3,], callback = JS(callback))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! As this works in my application, how could I write back the values into the Shiny app (i.e. save the new column names in the data set)?