# How to change colnames from DT::renderDT with editable = TRUE argument?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I used an adaptation of a topic right here to change the names of the columns of a DT table, however, it seems to me that the change in the new object is not occurring. Here is a reproducible example.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

teams <- data.frame(col1=1:2,col2=1:2)

shinyApp(
 ui = navbarPage("Questions",
  tabPanel("Programar questões",
   column(width=6,
    DTOutput('teamsTable')
    ),
   column(width=6,
    verbatimTextOutput('x11')
    ))),
 server = function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(teams=teams)   

  callback <- c(
   "table.on('dblclick.dt', 'thead th', function(e) {",
   "  var $th = $(this);",
   "  var index = $th.index();",
   "  var colname = $th.text(), newcolname = colname;",
   "  var $input = $('<input type=\"text\">')",
   "  $input.val(colname);",
   "  $th.empty().append($input);",
   "  $input.on('change', function(){",
   "    newcolname = $input.val();",
   "    if(newcolname != colname){",
   "      $(table.column(index).header()).text(newcolname);",
   "    }",
   "    $input.remove();",
   "  }).on('blur', function(){",
   "    $(table.column(index).header()).text(newcolname);",
   "    $input.remove();",
   "  });",
   "});"
  )

  output$teamsTable <- renderDT(
   rv[["teams"]],
   selection = list(target="row+column"),
   editable = 'cell',
   options = list(dom = 't'),
   rownames=FALSE,
   callback=JS(callback)
  )

  proxyTeams <- dataTableProxy("teamsTable")

  observeEvent(input$teamsTable_colname, {
   info <- input$teamsTable_colname
   rv[['teams']] <<- editData(rv[['teams']],input$teamsTable_colname,info,rownames=FALSE)
  }) 

  output$x11 <- renderPrint({
   names(rv[['teams']])
  })
 }
)
```

Double-click on the column name and change it. You will see that in the right column the name will not be changed. Any help I appreciate.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756377/how-to-edit-column-names-in-datatable-function-when-running-r-shiny-app/56559452#56559452) solution (Stéphane Laurent) only work "online", via ( tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.8.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.js")). I want a solution that work offline. My example was an adaption of same forum. However, I don't know how the R function understands what's in the "callback" argument, as I don't understand javascript. I would appreciate any small help!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- c(
  "var colnames = table.columns().header().to$().map(function() {",
  "  return this.innerHTML;",
  "}).get();",
  "Shiny.onInputChange('colnames', colnames);",
  "table.on('dblclick.dt', 'thead th', function(e) {",
  "  var $th = $(this);",
  "  var index = $th.index();",
  "  var colname = $th.text(), newcolname = colname;",
  "  var $input = $('<input type=\"text\">')",
  "  $input.val(colname);",
  "  $th.empty().append($input);",
  "  $input.on('change', function() {",
  "    newcolname = $input.val();",
  "    if(newcolname != colname){",
  "      $(table.column(index).header()).text(newcolname);",
  "      colnames[index] = newcolname;",
  "      Shiny.onInputChange('colnames', colnames);",
  "    }",
  "    $input.remove();",
  "  }).on('blur', function() {",
  "    $(table.column(index).header()).text(newcolname);",
  "    $input.remove();",
  "  });",
  "});"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("colnames"),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris[1:3,], callback = JS(callback), 
              options = list(ordering = FALSE))
  }, server = FALSE) 
  
  output[["colnames"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["colnames"]]                     
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]